# Recurrence Relation: Writing a recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, catalan

I'm trying to write a recurrence relation for this algorithm.But I've got confused with the "root" variable.Can anyone help me or suggest me a better recursive algorithm to count the number of possible binary trees with n nodes?

```
Algorithm countTrees(n) {
    if(n<=1) then return 1
    else {
        sum = 0
        for root=1 to root<= n do {
            left = countTrees(root-1)
            right = countTrees(n-root)
            sum = sum+(left*right)
        }
        return sum
    }
}
```

I've written this so far but I don't know how to deal with the root to solve this.

T(n) = n[T(root-1)+T(n-root)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is already a recurrence relation for the number of binary trees, just expressed as an algorithm. I guess you were stuck because you had a summation over a loop. Here it is in standard mathematical notation-- with the loop value changed from 1..n to 0..n-1 to be more standard:

```
C(0) = C(1) = 1
C(n) = sum(C(i) * C(n-i-1) for i = 0...n-1)
```

Writing it by hand (or with LaTeX) you'd use a summation sign rather than `sum`, but it's logically the same.

This is the recurrence relation for the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) (although normally the `C(1)` case would not be explicitly listed) and the Wikipedia page linked also includes the closed-form solution for the recurrence relation and proofs of its correctness.